# Reign of Terror on Through the Ages

Tags: through-the-ages

On the "Reign of Terror" event, do you lose one worker from the worker pool or the population bank?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On page 12 of the [rule book](http://files.boardgamegeek.com/file/download/5h68nqannh/Through_the_Ages_-_English_Rules.pdf?), it states the following

> When a card says you must "decrease"
>   your population, you return 1 yellow
>   token from your *Unused Workers Pool*.
>   If you have no *Unused Workers*, you
>   must remove (and return to your
>   *Yellow Bank*) a *Worker* from one of your cards. Do not forget to adjust
>   your indicators.

Therefore, you must lose a worker from your Pool (or one of your cards if no workers in your pool).

Comment: Reign of Terror states "lose" not "decrease". I wonder if there is a difference between those.

Comment: There is nothing in the rules to suggest they are treated any different.